# Add new row if it does not exists and get new id - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, insert-into, insert-select

I have a table

```
id(PK, AI)  name(UQ)
1             mike
2             ashly
3             nash
```

I want users are able to add new names. But if `name` already exists I don't want to add it again, and get the already existing name's `id`. If name does not exist I want `new id` of `new name`

I have tried many queries but none of them worked. That's why I am not going to write them here.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just do a **Select * FROM Table Where name = ashly** if no results **Insert Into Table name = ashly**

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. You say that if `name` already exists, you don't want to get back the existing ID for that `name`, you want a new row with a new ID. But you indicate that the `name` column is constrained `unique` (I assume that is what `UQ` means). You cannot have two rows with the same `name` if that column is constrained with `UNIQUE`.

Comment: **You say that if name already exists, you don't want to get back the existing ID for that name,**.  where did i said that? i said i want existing names id back

Comment: @code how i am gonna write **if no results** in sql?

Comment: If you get no results then you know you can insert this new name into your database